# My maven Java project in Eclipse doesn't generate jar file

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

If I use command line command like "mvn compile" and "mvn install", I see a jar file under target directory.

But if I build the same project from Eclipse using m2e plugin, I don't see a jar file but only compiled class directories under target directory but they are empty. Any insight on this problem?

Comment: Are you looking in the target directory?  Did you tell m2e to do a "maven install" build?

Comment: Stephen, does that mean that I need to modify pom.xml file? I didn't do anything other than importing the source directory.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

m2e won't build a jar unless you ask it to. (An exception to that is when you're using it with certain connectors to develop OSGi bundles, but I assume you aren't.)

To build a jar:

- Right-click on the project folder in the 'Package Explorer' view;
- Select "Run As"
- Select "Maven install"

Comment: same problem and still under target lib folder is empty