# How to execute .jar from pom.xml from cloned project in Dockerfile

Tags: java, maven, docker, dockerfile

I have this in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash wget git

RUN git clone https://MyProfile@bitbucket.org/MyProfile/myproject.git
RUN cd myproject

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/myproject

ONBUILD ADD . /

ONBUILD RUN mvn install

EXPOSE 4568
CMD ["java","-jar","/usr/src/app/myproject/target/ReadDocFile.jar"]
```

I was able to figure out how to install pom from that cloned repo - but I don't know where is my final .jar stored. I just can't find the .jar. Where does mvn install stores it? I don't wan't to use ONBUILD image because my project needs to be built from git repo. So how to solve this - how to find path where mvn install stores my final .jar for execution?

Comment: `mvn install` puts it in your local repo.

Comment: @Dave Newton - And how to put it on docker filesystem path? How to "grab" that .jar, from what type of path?

Comment: It'll be inside your target folder where you run `mvn install` from local git repo .

Comment: @Bandi Kishore but I'm not running mvn install from local git repo. As you can see, mvn install executes pom from git clone (and I checked it, it really does). Where then would be target folder, can you describe path (if it is not as in my example) ?

Comment: @DarioBB Sorry but I'm not sure about the question. I can explain how it currently works using your docker. First you change user's current directory to `/usr/src/app` using `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`. Then you clone the repo and cd to `myproject` directory using `WORKDIR /usr/src/app/myproject`. So your pom.xml lies in folder `/usr/src/app/myproject` and when you do `mvn install` from here, it creates your jar in a target folder inside `myproject`. So finally your jar should like at `/usr/src/app/myproject/target/`. Is this what you wanted to know about?

Comment: @Bandi Kishore - that's what I thought, but it isn't. .jar is not saved at /usr/src/app/myproject/target/, and ma app canno't start because it can't see .jar. Why is that? This just don't work, it's so frustrating: CMD ["java","-jar","/usr/src/app/myproject/target/ReadDocFile.jar"] (and it does work when all is defined without git part, when I'm using pom locally with modified code in Dockerfile)

Comment: @DarioBB Can you login to the docker and see if the target folder contains the jar? If not, inside the docker go to `/usr/src/app/myproject/` and manually run `mvn install`. After that verify if the file is now present and also check where is the jar file getting created (output of mvn install, should display it on the terminal). This is to check if there is any issue in running the `mvn install`.

Comment: @Bandi Kishore how could I check if jar is inside docker image? I won't be able to do that If I login to docker hub repository. I am not talking about docker hub. I got this at this time locally. And I don't want to do anything manually, this must be all run through Dockerfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132568/discussion-between-bandi-kishore-and-dariobb).

Comment: Why does the git clone have to happen within the Dockerfile? The checkout of a project's code should not have to happen within the build logic. Instead could I suggest to consider using an automated build server like Jenkins. Then you'll have a mechanism to checkout the code and simply using the Maven ONOBUILD image to take care of the code build

Comment: Mark O'Connor I've read that best practice advices are that repositories are not from local repositories, rather from online git sources "but it also helps ensure that the image available on the hub gets its base image (FROM entry) from the hub instead of whatever was available locally".  http://www.carlboettiger.info/2014/08/29/docker-notes.html I agree with you, but at this point, Jenkins configuration is complex and not option for us. So it's from online git repo, but just without automatic builds

Answer (score -1):

Your dependency is probably in your {user}/.m2/{the group name} if you did not set up maven yourself.

Your Jar should be in /target/

Comment: How to set it and how to find it? I got into the docker with /bin/bash and ran mvn install there. It showed this:

[INFO] Installing /usr/src/app/myproject/target/ReadDocFile.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/dario/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/apachepoi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

But non of it works when i put in last command in Dockerfile - CMD

Comment: P.s. I've tried to print all generated folders and files in docker container, container, but no .jar in target - I put this before line "EXPOSE 4568": 
RUN cd /usr/src/app/ 
RUN ls -altrR

Comment: Are you looking for your project's Jar?  You have to run mvn package

Comment: nija123098 ONBUILD RUN mvn install does the package too. Maybe this ONBUILD is something I don't need?

Comment: Then it should be in the target directory maven makes that is in the same folder as the src

Comment: What is that path nija123098? Just /src/myjar.jar ? Or what?

Comment: Go up one level from src, then it should be /target/TheJar.jar

Comment: Try mvn verify and looking again.

Comment: where.. after mvn install in Dockerfile or? mvn install goes fine. It says it finishes sucessfully. It poin't to .jar. But there isn't jar where it says

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993504/my-maven-java-project-in-eclipse-doesnt-generate-jar-file